# Server Aborts Connection with android app: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sockets, ddms

I have built my server using simple server socket code. It works perfect when I run a remote client sending a user input string but it gives the error below when I am trying to run the client code via an android app on android studio. Please help!

Eclipse DDMS Message

```
[2015-05-01 18:39:52 - ddmlib] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:675)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:342)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:521)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:831)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:799)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:759)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:648)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:576)
```

Then when I close android studio I get this in Eclipse

```
2015-05-01 19:24:06 - DeviceMonitor Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2015-05-01 19:24:07 - DeviceMonitor Connection attempts: 1
2015-05-01 19:24:09 - DeviceMonitor Connection attempts: 2
2015-05-01 19:24:11 - DeviceMonitor Connection attempts: 3
```

Comment: You application either crashed or was killed by the system. Look into logcat.

Answer (score 1):

The connection was being dropped by some switch because the machine bandwidth was too high (above the limit).

Use [this](http://www.netlimiter.com/) tool to find out what the machine bandwidth is.